# Close rdpcap function - Scapy

Tags: python, pcap, scapy, packet-capture

I have a script that loops through a lot of pcap files. For each pcap file I need to read it and then write some information to a txt file. I'm using the `rdcap` function from Scapy. Is there anyway to close the pcap file once I'm done reading it? My script has a memory leak and I'm worried this may be the culprit (via leaving many pcap files essentially open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspecting *Scapy*'s [source code](https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/src/cd8f482c8858e940959bf9c6c03a8d336db0edaf/scapy/utils.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#utils.py-526) reveals that the `rdpcap` function neglects to close the *pcap* file:

```
@conf.commands.register
def rdpcap(filename, count=-1):
    """Read a pcap file and return a packet list
count: read only <count> packets"""
    return PcapReader(filename).read_all(count=count)
```

I suggest you implement your own version of this function as follows:

```
def rdpcap_and_close(filename, count=-1):
    """Read a pcap file, return a packet list and close the file
count: read only <count> packets"""
    pcap_reader = PcapReader(filename)
    packets = pcap_reader.read_all(count=count)
    pcap_reader.close()
    return packets
```

---

I've created an issue for this problem [here](https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/issues/5149/rdpcap-and-wrpcap-file-descriptor-leak).

**EDIT:** The issue has been resolved in [this changeset](https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/commits/ae51bf369a63).